# Can the MAC address be "hidden"? ie that the information is not even delivered

Tags: mac-address

Along with the above question, I would also like to know how can the MAC address be properly changed? Moreover, can it be replaced by a casual sequence or there are specific addresses to use? Finally, once changed, can it be reset to the default value?

Comment: You are going to have to give us _a lot_ more information. Right now your question is so broad that it's not answerable. For example, what do you mean "not delivered"? What protocol are you using? HTTP? SSH? FTP? Bare TCP/IP? Carrying a USB Stick to your friend's house? As for "Can the MAC address be changed?" ... do you mean changed in the protocol message, or changed on your computer? If the latter, what operating system? what kind of hardware are you using?

Comment: Very badly written question. I suggest you organize your thoughts, do some Googling, and then come back to edit this question and make it better if you still have some ununderstood concepts or some specific question.

Comment: This is more of a question for https://superuser.com where it is very likely already answered but I am too lazy to search right now.

Comment: @Philipp User seems to want to hide / mask his presence. If so,  it might partially fall under Infosec because of that.

Comment: **Postal office clerk**: Hi, how can I help you today? **You**: I'd like to send a mail, but the receiver don't have an address. Can you send it to him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing an interface's [mac address](http://www.google.com/search?q=change%20mac%20address) is not [terribly difficult](http://www.howtogeek.com/192173/how-and-why-to-change-your-mac-address-on-windows-linux-and-mac/) [at all](http://linuxconfig.org/change-mac-address-with-macchanger-linux-command).

You can also change the MAC address through various other methods, such as a VPN, or on [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html). Not all of these methods will allow you to change your router's MAC address. You should have a MAC for each interface on your network. Many newer routers have more than one interface (wired, wireless, and router, for example).

---

### But is changing your MAC address the answer?

As for [hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_spoofing) your router's MAC address, be warned: many ISPs require your device's MAC address before they even *allow* you to connect to the internet. And even if you spoof it before providing the spoofed address, that is the address they expect you to be connecting from.

There are legitimate uses, such as spoofing a new router's mac address so you don't need to bother with calling customer service in order to get online.

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to mask your presence.

If you wanted to "hide," you'd need to change every single interface's MAC address. And even then, you can't really hide this way: the router is still tied to your name.  If you intend to "hide" using a mobile device, that is far more feasible. Just google "`change mac address devicename`". However, there are *many* other things you need to do to properly mask your presence. This is beyond the scope of my answer.

---

### Can you change your MAC address to anything you want?

> Moreover, can it be replaced by a casual sequence or there are specific addresses to use?

No. It has to be an appropriate mask and length. Usually, you need 12 [Hexadecimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), and the 2nd character can't be odd if it's unicast. For example, if unicast, the 2nd "digit" can't be any of the following:

1. **Digits**: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
2. **Letters**: B, D, F

> Finally, once changed, can it be reset to the default value?

If you're able to change it, then you *should* be able to change it again. Just set it back to what it was before.

Comment: Thank you so much! You addressed every point of the question in a very flowing way. Hands down the best aswer.